# Laravel Nova: The login form is in HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

## Context

I've installed Laravel Nova, executed the migrations and created the Nova user by following the docs https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/installation.html#installing-nova . Now I'm trying to login.

## Expected behavior

When I send the login form, I'm redirected to the backoffice panel.

## Actual behavior

When I send the login form, I'm redirected to a Chrome page "This page is not secured, are you sure you want to send your form data?" (approximately the English translation of the French displayed error :D ).

## Clues

The login form is shown at this URL: "https://.../nova/login".

The login form, however, contains this `action`: "http://.../nova/login" - NB: so it's not HTTPS, but HTTP.

## Question

Where could I set a Laravel and/or Nova config option to tell Nova to use `https` instead of `http` in the `action` of the login form Nova shows?

Comment: Have you updated your [environment settings](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/.env.example#L5) appropriately?

Comment: Yes, the `.env` file contains the good `APP_URL` (with HTTPS thus). Nova doesn't seem to use it. :-)

Comment: how did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Nova doesn't seem to use any environment/configuration option to be able to choose the good HTTP/HTTPS protocol, I've directly written the following, in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider` (NB: I don't really know the drawbacks of this solution so I don't recommend you to do it, even if in my case it worked well to fix this bug):

```
public function boot()
{
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Comment: Could someone tell us the drawbacks of this solution please? ^^

Comment: hey! any news on this?

Comment: I actually used forceSheme but still don't know the possible drawbacks.

Comment: but did you change the boot method in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider or in app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider? Is there any difference of doing so?

Comment: Appserviceprovider. Idk sry

Comment: One drawback would be that you would need to configure https on dev machines. I would recommend using a secure reverse proxy on public versions instead

Comment: and `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;` to have `URL` object !

Answer (score 0):

As JarsofJam points out `\URL::forceScheme('https');` is acceptable, but make sure to use proper guards for the environment. Ex:

```
if (config('app.env') !== 'local') {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

The major drawback here is that URL schemes are best centrally managed at a proxy level (ELB on AWS, or web server) on production environments.

If you specifically want to convert the Nova login action URL to HTTPS and not affect other URLs, you can override the login form view in your main application's views and adjust the action to use your `APP_URL` (with HTTP or HTTPS) config. Ex:

`nova/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php` -> `resources/views/vendor/nova/auth/login.blade.php`.